# Is my understanding of HashMap correct?

Tags: java, hashmap

HashMap produces a hashCode using the key user submits. Following can be two cases:

1) If two keys (Object) are same:

for instance

```
hashmap.put(1,"one");
hashmap.put(1,"another one");
```

Now , initially "one" will be inserted and then it will be overridden by "another one".

2) If the hashCode for two different objects are same:
for instance , if I have a bucket of size 5 and I try to:

```
hashmap.put(5,"this is five");
hashmap.put(25,"this is twenty five");
```

since hash % (SIZE-1) will point to the same location , LinkedList will be created to store the values as:
`"this is twenty five" -> "this is five"`

Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You're almost right.  However, Java doesn't necessarily use a linked list to store values that go in the same bucket.  If there are enough values in the bucket, it will use a red-black tree (a kind of binary search tree) instead of a list.  This is a new feature of Java 8 and can speed things up in some cases.  Other than that detail, your basic understanding is correct.

Comment: From a functional point of view you can ignore `HashMap` and just use the contract specified for `Map`. That the implementation is a `HashMap` becomes only interesting if you deal with non-functional aspects like performance.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is about `Map`'s in general. The behavior of a `Map` when you call `.put()` with the same key is a *documented* part of the `Map` *public contract*. Any (reasonable) `Map` implementation must behave this way, regardless of the specific implementation.

Your second question is about the *implementation* of `HashMap`; how `HashMap` resolves collisions is not part of its contract (though the documentation does describe the behavior), and therefore could (and does) change between releases. Not all `Map` implementations rely on `.hashCode()` and such implementations have no need to resolve such collisions.

The difference conceptually is between "correctness" and "efficiency". Because the collision resolution behavior is not a documented part of the contract it can change over time. Before Java 8 `HashMap` used a linked-list structure (not to be confused with `java.util.LinkedList`), as of Java 8 they instead sometimes use a red-black tree structure (not to be confused with `java.util.TreeMap`) for improved efficiency.

You might also be interested in [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20945574/113632), which explores the relationship between an Object's hashcode and equality.