# why Hashset remove duplicate object not work

Tags: java, set

I want use set to remove duplicate object,the UserEntity is like:

```
public class UserEntity {
    String name;
    int age;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserEntity [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }
    public UserEntity(String name, int age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o1) {
        UserEntity user=(UserEntity) o1;
        return this.age==user.age && user.name.equals(this.name);
    }
    
}
```

Then I create a set to add two user both called alex who`s age is 20,but there are two user in the set:

```
UserEntity user1 = new UserEntity("alex", 20);
UserEntity user2 = new UserEntity("alex", 20);
System.out.println(user1.equals(user2));
Set<UserEntity> set=new HashSet<>();
set.add(user1);
set.add(user2);
System.out.println(set.size());
```

The result is :

```
true
2
```

why the set do not remove duplicate object?

Comment: You need to override `Object#hashCode` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [**broke the contract**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), by not overriding `hashCode()`.

> **The general contract of hashCode is:**
>
> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
>   execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>   return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
>   comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain
>   consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
>   of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the
>   equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the
>   two objects must produce the same integer result.
> - It is not required
>   that if two objects are unequal according to the
>   equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on
>   each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.
>   However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct
>   integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of
>   hash tables.

---

And from `equals():`

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the **hashCode** method
> whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general
> contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must
> have equal hash codes.

[image]

---

As you broke the rules, the HashSet can't guarantee it will work properly. Its like it's been betrayed.

*This [shouldn't happen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20944638/2148953) in real code, because you shouldn't be violating the contract in real code*

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate a new object, it is exactly that, a new object, even if it contains the same data, the object hashCode is still different. You may want to look into overriding `Object#hashCode` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this. Add to your code and it will work.

```
public int hashCode() {
        return this.name.hashCode();
    }
```